# Accessing ComboBox inside a Datatemplate of a listbox from c# code behind in metro application?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

i have a combo box present inside a list-box , listbox has a datatemplate in which this combobox and other elements  resides .

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstbxbProducts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="547" Margin="0,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1044" RenderTransformOrigin="0.600000023841858,0.5">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Width="80" Orientation="Horizontal">
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding prdnum}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>     
                           <TextBlock Text="  -" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Width="400">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding prddsc}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>   
                       <StackPanel Width="300">
                            <ComboBox Name="cmbbxbUMselec" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="200" FontSize="24"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Width="180">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding prcby_prc}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                       <StackPanel Width="100">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding stdordqty, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" ></TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My doubt is that i am not able access the combobox present inside a the datatemplate of the listbox ,
i want to bind a list to the combobox from c# codebehind

```
cmbbxbUMselec.DataContext = lstumcods;
```

in this way from code behind but i am not  able access the combobox present inside a the datatemplate of the listbox

Please let me know how can i work around this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you want to set up the ComboBox from code-behind? Would you accept a solution that involves a different binding in the XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

First i've changed your listbox to this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstbxbProducts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="547" Margin="0,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1044" RenderTransformOrigin="0.600000023841858,0.5">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <ComboBox x:Key="myComboBox" Name="cmbbxbUMselec" ></ComboBox>
        </ListBox.Resources>           
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Width="80" Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding prdnum}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>     
                       <TextBlock Text="  -" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Width="400">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding prddsc}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>   
                   <StackPanel Width="300">
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbbxbUMselec" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myComboBox}, Path=ItemsSource, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Width="200" FontSize="24"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Width="180">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding prcby_prc}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                   <StackPanel Width="100">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding stdordqty, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" ></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Note that i've added a item in your listbox.resources.

On code-behind i've added the following code:

```
            var cb = lstbxbProducts.Resources.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key.ToString() == "myComboBox");
        ((ComboBox)cb.Value).ItemsSource = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
```

Don't forget to add "System.Linq" to your assemblies, otherwise it will not work.
Now try it with your "true" source and tell us if its working.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing it in XAML rather than code-behind, here's an idea.

I assume your ListBox is defined somewhere inside a UserControl, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyUserControl">
    <!-- Other elements here -->
    <ListBox x:Name="lstbxbProducts">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- etc... -->
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

If lstumcods is a public property defined in the code-behind of the UserControl, then you could try this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding lstumcods, ElementName=MyUserControl" />
```