# Metro App Access DataTemplate Control

Tags: .net, xaml, listbox, microsoft-metro, datatemplate

I have a `ListBox` control with the following layout, that has a custom control in it:

```
<ListBox x:Name="testList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:MyUserControl x:Name="testListItem"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I am trying to access `MyUserControl` from codebehind like so:

```
testList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(testList.SelectedItem);
```

Unfortunately, it always returns null. I've read somewhere that setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualized="False"` on the `ListBox` in XAML fixes this.

But this property is not available in Metro. Does someone know of a way on how this could be achieved?

Comment: **RESOLVED**

Followed this approach:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370081/accessing-combobox-inside-a-datatemplate-of-a-listbox-from-c-sharp-code-behind-i][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370081/accessing-combobox-inside-a-datatemplate-of-a-listbox-from-c-sharp-code-behind-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED** Followed this approach:

[Reference Datatemplate Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370081/accessing-combobox-inside-a-datatemplate-of-a-listbox-from-c-sharp-code-behind-i)

Works well. Enjoy!